# How do I open about:config in Firefox on Android?

Tags: firefox-for-android

A lot of settings on Firefox for Android need `about:config`, but I cannot open it by typing in the address bar.

Here is a screenshot 15 seconds after I typed `about:config` in the address bar and pressed enter.

[image: write about:config in the address bar]

Here is a screenshot showing the version of Firefox on my phone.

[image: Firefox version]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

`about:config` is disabled in builds other than Nightly
From [this answer](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1300502#question-reply):

> You can access about:config in the Nightly build of Firefox for Android, available from the Google Play store .

Comment: `about:config` also works in Firefox Beta.