# How do I disable Javascript in the stable version of Firefox in Android?

Tags: settings, firefox-for-android, javascript

Sometimes I need to disable Javascript on some webpages for various reasons. From [a rather old post on Mozilla Support](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/994809) and some other sources, I learned that it is done through `about:config`.

However, from the answer on [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/237146/how-do-i-open-aboutconfig-in-firefox-on-android/237148) on SE Android, I learned that `about:config` is no longer accessible on the stable version of Firefox for Android.

So I am back to the square 1, how do I disable Javascript in Firefox on Android?

I have the following constraints in roughly the order of decreasing concern. Please keep these constraints in consideration while answering the question, but I am still welcome to learn about solutions that violate some of these constraints.

1. I do not want to use nightly or beta versions. They might have security vulnerabilities or unexpected behavior.
2. I do not want to change any Firefox configuration files on the file system, unless from within Firefox. I don't know much about Android application and I am afraid I might break something while messing with files.
3. I do not want to install any add-on on Firefox unless it is opensource or is widely known to be trustworthy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I do not want to install any add-on on Firefox unless it is opensource or is widely known to be trustworthy.

You're in luck today. Install [NoScript Security Suite](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/addon/noscript/) addon by Giorgio Maone. It is a GNU GPL 2.0 licensed addon. Has more than a decade of history of development, support and trust. It is a "Recommended" extension from Mozilla. It is also [bundled with](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_(network)#Tor_Browser) Tor Browser.

As per [Firefox Help](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/add-on-badges#w_recommended-extensions), meaning of Recommended extension is:

> Recommended extensions are editorially curated extensions that meet the highest standards of security, functionality, and user experience. Firefox staff, along with community participation, selects each extension and manually reviews them for security and policy compliance before they receive Recommended status.

Your desired usage of web browser is in contrast to what NoScript offers. As such you need to configure this addon.

As I see it, you want all of your websites to work "with javascript enabled", except a few where you need "javascript disabled". To achieve that, install that addon in your Firefox for Android.  Open NoScript page (three-dots line in Firefox status bar -> Addons -> NoScript)

Click on the icon (with a small wrench) next to green colored Reload icon. Below in that page, in "General", under "Default" tick/check all items. This is needed so that websites don't break for you, because this is desirable in your question.

Load the website in your browser where you want javascript disabled. Open Noscript page again. To the website names/entries listed there, press CUSTOM and uncheck/untick *script* This would disable javascript for the entry/domain you selected.

If you have many websites where you don't want to repeat this procedure, go into Noscript settings, under "Per-site Permissions", add your domains and configure "CUSTOM" settings there.

This is a one-time only effort, but should work for long.

Comment: The settings seem to be a bit twisty but I hope I will get get better with it.

Comment: @AbdullahBaig post a question if you don't get better. :D